# Angular innerHTML contents are jumbled. Only the last innerHTML is displayed correctly

Tags: html, css, angular

In my Angular project (version 8) I am creating a list of static HTML from database and rendering it in parent HTML. Only the last `div` having `innerHTML` is rendered correctly, all the preceding divs having child html is not rendered correctly. The contents are jumbled. Basically the child html's style is not honored except for the last child html.
I am using sanitize html pipe for the div.
The angular component `onInit` queries DB in a loop. Each get call returns HTML text which is appended to an array of strings. The HTML text is basically PDF to HTML converted file. Each of the HTML file has its own style tag.

My guess is that only the last innerHTML's style is applied to all the preceding child `innerHTML` hence the jumbled contents (unless my guess is incorrect)
Any suggestion to solve the issue ?

HTML

```
  <div  *ngFor="let qBank of tsqm.selectedQuestions; let i = index">
       
          <div class="page">
            <div  [innerHTML]="questionDataFromHtml[i] | 
                                 sanitizeHtml"></div> 
          </div>
   </div>
```

Sanitize HTML:

```
      @Pipe({ name: 'sanitizeHtml'})
      export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
       constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
       transform(value: string): SafeHtml {
       return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Component:

```
 ngOnInit(){
   this.questionset = this.storage.get(quesId);
   //pseudo code
   forEach(item in this.questionset){
    this.getHTMLfromDB(item)
   }
 }

 getHTMLfromDB(question: QuestionBank) {

  this.Service.getQuestionHtmlFile(question.questionFilePath).subscribe(res => 
  {
    
    this.questionDataFromHtml.push(res.text());
    question.questionData.questionDataFromHtml = res.text();
});
```

Correct display. Question1 and Question2 are same
[Correct display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwJQr.png)

Incorrect display. Question1 and Question2 are different
[Incorrect display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCOOd.png)

Stackblitz:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kuyhv3?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: But why do you use innerHtml instead of ngFor?

Comment: I have used ngFor in my actual code. The above code was for debugging purpose. I will add the actual html contents

Comment: Could you post the excepted HTML content and the jumbled HTML content?

Comment: I'am prety sure should be this.questionDataFromHtml.push(res.text) -see that there're no `()`. I imagine text is a property of your json object

Comment: please provide a stackblitz.

Comment: @ChrisHappy I have uploaded the images for your reference

Comment: @Eliseo res.text( ) is correct. I am storing the response from rest api and adding to the array

Comment: Sorry, I imagined that res is an object -not a class-, so not exist res.text()

Comment: @AakashGarg please find the stackblitz link <https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kuyhv3?file=src/app/hello.component.ts>

Answer (score 0):

The issue is all the css styling is overridden and the final values are applied.

Use id/class to apply the style to specific component.

I've made changes to your stackblitz example. [Check here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-97ofyi?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

*In hello.component.ts*

Applied red color to the text using text-red id.

```
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  
html1 =
    "<html><head><style>  #text-blue {color:blue;}</style></head><body><h2 id='text-blue'>Inner HTML1 in red</h2></body></html>";
  
html2 =
    "<html><head><style>  #text-red {color:red;}</style></head><body><h2 id='text-red'>Inner HTML2 in blue</h2></body></html>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Here we are assuming that each of the innerHtml is editable and is static in nature. In real scenario I am converting pdf to html and stored in DB. The styling varies depending on the contents of the pdf. Do you have better solution for this?

Comment: I guess you're looking for dynamic styling, If yes, this might help you.. Using ngStyle in Angular for dynamic styling https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/using-ngstyle-in-angular-for-dynamic-styling

Comment: Yes, I want each of the child html to retains its individual styling. The angular project should fetch each of the html string from DB  and display it as it is. Neither the parent styling should affect child styling nor each child's styling should interfere with other child html

Comment: Go through that article, understand dynamic styling and make changes. If you need any further help, provide a stackblitz with sample data. I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using iFrame tag and srcdoc attribute. The backend service will return html text to angular. After DOM sanitizing the html documents are displayed in the iFrames.